# How to increment name attribute with number after adding the same section jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a duplicate section in my form, which is working fine. I have multiple input fields with type radio. What it does here after adding the same section it duplicates the form with the same name attribute, but I want to change the name attribute in all input field something like this.

**Normal:**

```
<input type=radio name="kid"> Yes
<input type=radio name="kid"> No

<input type=radio name="sports">Yes
<input type=radio name="sports">No
```

**When user add the same section it should be like this**

```
<input type=radio name="kid1"> Yes
<input type=radio name="kid1"> No

<input type=radio name="sports2">Yes
<input type=radio name="sports2">No
```

**I'm using jQuery cloning function**

```
.on('click', '.addButton', function() {
          var $template = $('#taskTemplate')
          var count = 1;
          var name = $('.')
              $clone    = $template
                              .clone(true,true)
                              .removeClass('hide')
                              .removeAttr('id')
                              .insertBefore($template)
                              .find('input[type=radio]').attr({ name: name+count})
      })
```

**This is the line of code doing:**

```
.find('input[type=radio]').attr({ name: name+count})

<input type=radio name="1"> Yes
<input type=radio name="1"> No

<input type=radio name="1">Yes
<input type=radio name="1">No
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Your example doesn't contain any `name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the name variable:

```
.on('click', '.addButton', function() {
      var $template = $('#taskTemplate');
      var count = 1;
      var name =  $('#taskTemplate').find('input[type=radio]').attr('name');
          $clone    = $template
                          .clone(true,true)
                          .removeClass('hide')
                          .removeAttr('id')
                          .insertBefore($template)
                          .find('input[type=radio]').attr({ name: name+count})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  $('.addButton').on('click', function() {

    var $div = $('div[id^="taskTemplate"]:last');

    var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1; 

    var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'klon'+num );

    $div.clone().prop('id', 'taskTemplate'+num).insertAfter($div)
    .find('input[type=radio]').each( function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');                            

        $(this).attr('name', name+num);
    })
      });
```